# How to Validate JSON data by Using JSONSchema in jMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonschema, jmeter-plugins

For my request I am getting the `json` response. So, I wanted to use `JSONSchema` for the structural and data type validation in `jMeter`. 
How can I achieve this in a best way?

Is there any plugins available in `jMeter` to perform these kind of tasks?

**Example** :
Response Json is

```
{
  "id": "60D5B6D2-9607-4E23-91D0-14EB5EA806EA",
  "imp": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tagid": "759926",
      "banner": {
        "w": 300,
        "h": 250,
        "topframe": 1,
        "api": [
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSONSchema is

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "imp": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "tagid": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "banner": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "w": {
                "type": "integer",
                "minimim": 10,
                "maximum": 150
              },
              "h": {
                "type": "integer",
                "minimim": 10,
                "maximum": 150
              },
              "topframe": {
                "type": "integer",
                "minimim": 10,
                "maximum": 150
              },
              "api": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
              "w",
              "h",
              "topframe",
              "api"
            ]
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": [
          "id",
          "tagid",
          "banner"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "id",
    "imp"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in support of validating a JSON object against the schema so you will have to do some scripting like described in [Validate JSON against Schema in Java](http://wilddiary.com/validate-json-against-schema-in-java/) article. Just in case the referenced link dies, you will need the following libraries in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

```
activation-1.1.jar
btf-1.2.jar
guava-16.0.1.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
jackson-coreutils-1.8.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
joda-time-2.3.jar
jopt-simple-4.6.jar
json-schema-core-1.2.5.jar
json-schema-validator-2.2.6.jar
jsr305-3.0.0.jar
libphonenumber-6.2.jar
mailapi-1.4.3.jar
msg-simple-1.1.jar
rhino-1.7R4.jar
uri-template-0.9.jar
```

The fastest and the easiest way of obtaining them is creating the minimal [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-coreutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

and execute [mvn dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) command.

After that you will be able to use something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingMessage;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;


public class ValidationUtils {

    public static final String JSON_V4_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER = "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#";
    public static final String JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT = "$schema";

    public static JsonNode getJsonNode(String jsonText)
            throws IOException
    {
        return JsonLoader.fromString(jsonText);
    } // getJsonNode(text) ends

    public static JsonNode getJsonNode(File jsonFile)
            throws IOException
    {
        return JsonLoader.fromFile(jsonFile);
    } // getJsonNode(File) ends

    public static JsonNode getJsonNode(URL url)
            throws IOException
    {
        return JsonLoader.fromURL(url);
    } // getJsonNode(URL) ends

    public static JsonNode getJsonNodeFromResource(String resource)
            throws IOException
    {
        return JsonLoader.fromResource(resource);
    } // getJsonNode(Resource) ends

    public static JsonSchema getSchemaNode(String schemaText)
            throws IOException, ProcessingException
    {
        final JsonNode schemaNode = getJsonNode(schemaText);
        return _getSchemaNode(schemaNode);
    } // getSchemaNode(text) ends

    public static JsonSchema getSchemaNode(File schemaFile)
            throws IOException, ProcessingException
    {
        final JsonNode schemaNode = getJsonNode(schemaFile);
        return _getSchemaNode(schemaNode);
    } // getSchemaNode(File) ends

    public static JsonSchema getSchemaNode(URL schemaFile)
            throws IOException, ProcessingException
    {
        final JsonNode schemaNode = getJsonNode(schemaFile);
        return _getSchemaNode(schemaNode);
    } // getSchemaNode(URL) ends

    public static JsonSchema getSchemaNodeFromResource(String resource)
            throws IOException, ProcessingException
    {
        final JsonNode schemaNode = getJsonNodeFromResource(resource);
        return _getSchemaNode(schemaNode);
    } // getSchemaNode() ends

    public static void validateJson(JsonSchema jsonSchemaNode, JsonNode jsonNode)
            throws ProcessingException
    {
        ProcessingReport report = jsonSchemaNode.validate(jsonNode);
        if (!report.isSuccess()) {
            for (ProcessingMessage processingMessage : report) {
                throw new ProcessingException(processingMessage);
            }
        }
    } // validateJson(Node) ends

    public static boolean isJsonValid(JsonSchema jsonSchemaNode, JsonNode jsonNode) throws ProcessingException
    {
        ProcessingReport report = jsonSchemaNode.validate(jsonNode);
        return report.isSuccess();
    } // validateJson(Node) ends

    public static boolean isJsonValid(String schemaText, String jsonText) throws ProcessingException, IOException
    {
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaText);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNode(jsonText);
        return isJsonValid(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJson(Node) ends

    public static boolean isJsonValid(File schemaFile, File jsonFile) throws ProcessingException, IOException
    {
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaFile);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNode(jsonFile);
        return isJsonValid(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJson(Node) ends

    public static boolean isJsonValid(URL schemaURL, URL jsonURL) throws ProcessingException, IOException
    {
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaURL);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNode(jsonURL);
        return isJsonValid(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJson(Node) ends    

    public static void validateJson(String schemaText, String jsonText) throws IOException, ProcessingException{
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaText);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNode(jsonText);
        validateJson(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJson(text) ends

    public static void validateJson(File schemaFile, File jsonFile) throws IOException, ProcessingException{
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaFile);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNode(jsonFile);
        validateJson(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJson(File) ends

    public static void validateJson(URL schemaDocument, URL jsonDocument) throws IOException, ProcessingException{
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaDocument);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNode(jsonDocument);
        validateJson(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJson(URL) ends

    public static void validateJsonResource(String schemaResource, String jsonResource) throws IOException, ProcessingException{
        final JsonSchema schemaNode = getSchemaNode(schemaResource);
        final JsonNode jsonNode = getJsonNodeFromResource(jsonResource);
        validateJson(schemaNode, jsonNode);
    } // validateJsonResource() ends

    private static JsonSchema _getSchemaNode(JsonNode jsonNode)
            throws ProcessingException
    {
        final JsonNode schemaIdentifier = jsonNode.get(JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT);
        if (null == schemaIdentifier){
            ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).put(JSON_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER_ELEMENT, JSON_V4_SCHEMA_IDENTIFIER);
        }

        final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
        return factory.getJsonSchema(jsonNode);
    } // _getSchemaNode() ends
}
```

in [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps).

Answer (score 0):

try [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) JMeter plugin which allows you to perform validations of JSON documents (like structure, values, type one at a time),  but not for schema validation.

You can download using [JMeter-plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) **OR**

Manually download the jar and put it `/lib/ext` folder and restart JMeter.

---

From Docs:

> This component allows you to perform validations of JSON documents.
>
> First, it will parse the JSON and fail if the data is not JSON.
>
> Second, it will search for specified path, using syntax from Jayway
>   JsonPath 1.2.0. If the path is not found, it will fail.
>
> Third, if JSON path was found in the document, and validation against
>   expected value was requested, it will perform validation. For the null
>   value there is special checkbox in the GUI.

Comment: How can I validate structure of JSON using JSON Path Assertion ?

Comment: again not complete structure. when you write assertion using `Jayway JsonPath 1.2.0` style, when the path to the element is not found, raises failure, which is indirectly ou are testing the structure. Refer second point in `Docs` section of my answer